# Why take the logarithm of likelihood function when finding MLE

Tags: probability, statistics

To calculate the MLE, I see that we can easily take the logarithm of the likelihood function like so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Maximum_likelihood

I have the following likelihood function:

L(λ) = (λ^3)(e^(-9λ))

I know that I can use the procedure described in the wikipedia article (take the natural log of both sides and find the MLE). Can I also take the derivative and use the product rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that in calculus, the derivative is a linear operator:  $$(f+g)' = f' + g'.$$  But it is not a multiplicative operator:  $$(fg)' = f'g + g'f \ne f'g'.$$  So, when we talk about the MLE of a sample, a product naturally arises because the joint distribution of independent observations $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is given by the *product* of the marginal distributions of each observation; i.e., $$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n \mid \boldsymbol \theta) = \prod f(x_i \mid \boldsymbol \theta).$$  So to find the maximum likelihood, it is usually easier to apply a monotone transformation to the likelihood (thus preserving the location of relative extrema) that converts multiplication to addition--this is the logarithm function.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot

Comment: would using the product rule work in this case? It seems your answer implies no

Comment: In theory, solving for the critical points of $(fg)' = 0$ yields the same values as for solving $(\log f)' + (\log g)' = 0$.  But, usually, one way is **easier** than the other.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Since the log is a monotonic function, the log-likelihood will have maxima in exactly the same places where the likelihood has maxima. So both methods will give the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use any function that has its maximum at the same place as the likelihood function.  This is because you don't care about the value of the function.  Instead, *using* that value, you want to solve for your parameter $\lambda$.

Log function has two nice properties that work very well for us:

- Its value is the highest wherever the likelihood function is at its highest (the monotonicity that other commenters have already mentioned).
- Log converts exponents into factors, and products into sums:
  e.g., $log(x^px^q) = p\ log(x) + q\ log(x)$
- To compute the maximum (the M in MLE), it is easy to take derivative of a log function, compared to the original likelihood function: $\frac{d}{dx}log(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

There is a nice practical benefit to the second point above, when you're using statistical software.  Computers don't have to deal with very small fractions as they keep computing products.  Imagine a Bernoulli distribution with $p = 0.2$.  For large $n$, $0.2^n$ and $(1-0.2)^n$ quickly become small values.  For $n = 10$, the first factor is already $0.0000001024$.